# Share projects effectively in Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, shared-libraries

I'm new in node world and I'm in facing with a problem,
Currently I'd made a split in the project (in ts) where I work in two new packages(using ts also), to be shared between applications.
All this code are in the same repo, popularly called "monorepo". Below I'll illustrate how this are joined.

But even using the npm link when we made the transpile, from this ts to js these code wasn't included in the final build, to solve this I created two npm packages.

Therefore, apparently this have been adding more complexity into development, because when we need change something in these packages, we need do a link between these package and the project and then if we made some new modification in the packages, it's needed run the npm build in these packages to update the source to be used, because I import the package transpiled (I have some issues regarding the es6 and your imports, node don't accepted it).

I would like how can I improve this method to be less bureaucratic and more effective.

To illustrate my current situation:

```
/Repo
|_ _/my-app
|   |_ _/node_modules
|   |    |_ _/package-A (npm package)
|   |    |_ _/package-B (npm package)
|_ _/package-A
|_ _/package-B
|_ _/others-apps
```

Comment: Sounds like something [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) was created for.

Comment: Thanks @cbr I'll take a look on this.